# jQuery disable and loading div for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, razor

Working on an ASP.NET app with some JavaScript (jQuery specifically) on the front end. I have some icons being loaded on mobile in a div which are "scrunched" together. They appear on the screen but they don't have a height.

My idea of a solution is to disable the div and maybe popup a small spinner until the icons fully load. I would like to enable the div and remove the spinner once the div loads, but I am unsuccessful in capturing a "load" event from that jQuery div. As well, I don't know how to disable a div in jQuery and bring up a spinner (I have used other frameworks which had methods to do that). After searching online, there seems to be a discrepency in what is best practice and what jQuery can currently do. Our project is jQuery 3.2.1. Currently, the code just goes through a recursive loop of all descendents of a particular div and checks if their heights are greater than 0 and then realigns their positioning.

**So my questions are:** how do I wait until load for a div in jQuery 3.2.1 (or is it possible)? How do I disable the div and gray it out? How do I bring up a loading spinner?

Below is our code base to see the solution that was made originally to poll for the height before realignment.

Here is the code of the cshtml div:

```
<div class="MyFavorites" style="position: relative;">
<h5 class="title-section">@Model.MyFavoriteTitle</h5>
@if (Model.MyFavoriteCustomizeLink != null)
{
    <a href="@Model.MyFavoriteCustomizeLink.Url" class="favorites-customize"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i></a>
}
<div class="row collapse panel favorites">
    <div class="row" data-equalizer>
        @if (Model.FavoriteLinks != null && Model.FavoriteLinks.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.FavoriteLinks.Where(link => !link.IsDeleted))
            {
                var url = (item.LinkUrl ?? String.Empty).Trim();
                var target = (item.LinkTarget ?? String.Empty).Trim();
                if (item != null && item.FavoriteIcon != null) //temporary fix for null issues
                {
                    var fi = item.FavoriteIcon;
                    <div class="column small-6 favorite-item" data-equalizer-watch>
                        <a href="@url" target="@target" class="item">
                            @if (fi != null && fi.FavoriteIconImage != null)
                            {
                                @RenderImage(item, o => o.FavoriteIcon.FavoriteIconImage, new { Class = "icon" }, isEditable: false);
                            }
                            <span>@item.FavoriteTitle</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <p class="column empty-list-message">@Html.Raw(UtilityHelpers.SafeRichTextHtml(Model.MyFavoriteListEmptyMessage_HomePage))</p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript code that does the polling currently:

```
function equalizeFavorites(attempts) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            jQuery('.favorite-item').css('min-height', 'auto');
            var fiheight = 0;
            jQuery('.favorite-item').each(function (i, el) {
                console.log("Element i: " + i + ", OuterHeight: " + jQuery(el).outerHeight() + ", Height: " + jQuery(el).height());
                fiheight = (jQuery(el).height() > fiheight) ? jQuery(el).outerHeight() : fiheight;
                fiheight = (fiheight > 200) ? 200 : fiheight;
            });
            jQuery('.favorite-item').css('min-height', fiheight);
            if (fiheight == 0) {
                //jQuery('.favorite-item').hide();
                attempts++;
                if (attempts < 5) { equalizeFavorites(attempts); }
            }
            else {
                //jQuery('.favorite-item').show();
            }
        }, 250);

    }
```